# How to get the characters in row and column?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to extract the words in a 2d array so I need to do a row and column inspection so that I could get the characters.

**Example:**
I have an array that contains a 2d dimensional which is shown in this photo [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSu2A.png) and this is the code that stores the array. I already resize it into 15x15

```
arr2 = np.array([my_list2])
arr2 = arr2.reshape(15,15)
```

The problem is every time I extracted the characters it won't give me the a for the apple. 
`E
A
G
L
E
P
P
L
E`

This is the code that let me extract the strings: 
`board_size = 15
print(arr2)`

```
for i in range(board_size):
    for j in range(board_size):
        val = arr2[i,j]
        if val != '0' :
        print(val)
```

`
The output I need is to be able to display eagle and apple.

Comment: You code goes linearily through your data - by line &column- the A is in the line with eagle and printed when it is passed. Your code does not look for words or for characters that were already printed earlier - how should it know that the `A` is used twice??

Comment: I'm planning to use a code that can scan row and column to get the A in apple.

Comment: Yeah .. but your code does _exactly_ what you coded .. there is nothing in it that will scan for a "reused" A ... so what is your problem with the code?

Comment: Oh the problem is that I need to get "A" for apple. Any suggestion what method i could use to get the word eagle and apple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to achieve what you want to do without numpy:

```
def print_non_0_len_ge_1(li):
    """removes 0 from front/back of line, prints rest of line if > 1 consecutive letter
    splitting at 0 between words."""
    for line in li:
        no_zero = ''.join(line).strip("0").split("0")
        for p in no_zero:
            if len(p)>1:
                print(*p,sep="\n")
                print("")   

data = [['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
        ['0', '0', '0', 'E', 'A', 'G', 'L', 'E', '0', '0'], 
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', 'P', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', 'P', '0', 'P', '0', '0', '0'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', 'L', '0', 'I', '0', '0', '0'], 
        ['0', '0', '0', 'C', 'E', 'R', 'E', 'A', 'L', '0'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]

# apply to lines
print_non_0_len_ge_1(data)

# apply to transposed data to get the columns
print_non_0_len_ge_1(zip(*data))
```

Output:

```
E
A
G
L
E

C
E
R
E
A
L

A
P
P
L
E

P
I
E
```

---

You can solve it similarily if using numpy - just remove the starting / ending 0, split at 0 and apply to normal and transposed data.

The method has a drawback - you need `0` between any non-word-forming characters in both directions to allow it to work (you can not use "EGG" starting ad "(E)agle" because you get `GP` twice from it.

Comment: How do I get the strings after the display?

Comment: You declare a list outside the for loop (`mystrings = []`) and after `print(*p,sep="\n")` you do `mystrings.append(p)`. This is somewhere between trivial and moderate difficulty - extracting the string is as easy as seeing where it is printed ... if you do not understand the code so well - maybe you should try some easier stuff first to get a better grasp of python?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you might iterate through rows and columns (using indexing) and use list comprehension to remove `0`s. Consider following example

```
a = np.array([['T','E','S','T'],
['0','0','0','E'],
['0','0','0','S'],
['0','0','0','T']])
height,width = a.shape
for i in range(height):
    word = ''.join([j for j in a[i] if j!='0'])
    if len(word)>=2: print(word)
for i in range(width):
    word = ''.join([j for j in a[:,i] if j!='0'])
    if len(word)>=2: print(word)
```

output:

```
TEST
TEST
```

`a` is hardcoded value for example clarity, note usage of `a.shape` which is more elegant than magic numbers.

As noted in comment it had one flaw in original form, to avoid that problem, `for`s should look following way:

```
for i in range(height)
    words = ''.join(a[i]).split('0')
    words = [i for i in words if len(i)>=2]
    if words: print(words)
for i in range(width):
    words = ''.join(a[:,i]).split('0')
    words = [i for i in words if len(i)>=2]
    if words: print(words)
```

Note that now `words` is list, this method can also detected two or more words in one row or column.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Its for my project I am very thankful for this page. Thank you.

Comment: It could only detect 2 words if >=2? what wil happen if words are four?

Comment: It detects any numbers of words which consist of 2 or more letters, without that check it would also print single letters (for example `E` for second row).

Comment: There is a drawback in this method. It counts 2 or more words yes? I tried your code and it will also count words for example a word figs created in 3rd row. It will also read Tf, ei and sg.